# Amazon ECS - Task Definitions

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, taskdef

I am working with ECS, and I have one task definition, where I added a few ENVs

Should I send all ENVs each time, when I create a new revision for the task definition ?

I create new revision by the task

For example:

```
aws ecs register-task-definition --family test --container-definitions '[{"name": "test", "image": "<URL_TO_IMAGE>/test:latest", "memory": 900}]'
```

Comment: They don't stack, so you need to provide all the things each time. If you want to bump these revisions without that type of flow you could use Terraform or cloudformation to rev them and not rely on the CLI

Comment: As Marc said or just use  json/yaml file and refer to that with your cli command

Comment: very strange behavior, from the web interface the aws saves all ENVs and other parameters, from the terminal/cli aws doesn't save.. anyway, thanks, guys.

Comment: @MarcYoung what do you mean by "they don't stack"?